# .NET equivalents of Some Python Functions

Tags: c#, python, porting

I am trying to port some Python code to .NET, and I was wondering if there were equivalents of the following Python functions in .NET, or some code snippets that have the same functionality.

```
os.path.split()
os.path.basename()
```

**Edit**

os.path.basename() in Python returns the tail of os.path.split, not the result of System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(path)

I think the following method creates a suitable port of the os.path.split function, any tweaks are welcome. It follows the description of os.path.split from http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html as much as possible I believe.

```
    public static string[] PathSplit(string path)
    {
        string head = string.Empty;
        string tail = string.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            head = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            tail = path.Replace(head + "\\", "");
        }

        return new[] { head, tail };
    }
```

I'm unsure about the way I'm returning the head and tail, as I didn't really want to pass out the head and tail via parameters to the method.

Comment: @Tom - Good point. I've re-written my answer to reflect the issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**os.path.basename()**

<s>The alternative is `System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(path);`:</s>

```
System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot("C:\\Foo\\Bar.xml") // Equals C:\\
```

***Edit***: The above returned the first path of the path, where `basename` should return the tail of the path. See the code below for an example of how this could be achieved.

**os.path.split()**

Unfortunately there's no alternative to this as there's no .Net equivalent. The closest you can find is `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path)`, however if your path was **C:\Foo**, then `GetDirectoryName` would give you **C:\Foo** instead of **C:** and **Foo**. This would only work if you wanted to get the Directory Name of an actual file path.

So you'll have to write some code like the following to break these down for you:

```
public void EquivalentSplit(string path, out string head, out string tail)
{

    // Get the directory separation character (i.e. '\').
    string separator = System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();

    // Trim any separators at the end of the path
    string lastCharacter = path.Substring(path.Length - 1);
    if (separator == lastCharacter)
    {
        path = path.Substring(0, path.Length - 1);
    }

    int lastSeparatorIndex = path.LastIndexOf(separator);

    head = path.Substring(0, lastSeparatorIndex);
    tail = path.Substring(lastSeparatorIndex + separator.Length,
        path.Length - lastSeparatorIndex - separator.Length);

}
```

Comment: You should use `Path.PathSeparator` instead of verbatim "\\", this could be run on mono you know! Technically that's more accurate too because in python the `os` & `os.path` namespaces are responsible for abstracting platform independant functionality too.

Comment: @Aren B - Actually, you should use the `DirectorySeparatorChar` as `PathSeparator` is probably something like `;`.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the `System.IO.Path` Class.

It has many functions you can use to get the same functionality.

- `Path.GetDirectoryName(string)`
- For split, you'll probably want to use `String.Split(...)` on the actual path name. You can get the OS Dependant seperator by `Path.PathSeparator`.
- In the case that im missing the point about `os.path.split` and you want the file name, use `Path.GetFileName(string)`.

*Please Note: You can explore all the members of the `System.IO` namespace by using the **Object Browser** (Ctrl+Alt+J) in Visual Studio. From here you go `mscorlib` -> `System.IO` and all the classes will be discoverable there.*

It's like Intellisense on crack :)

Comment: AFAIK `os.path.split()` is not the same as `String.Split()`. `os.path.split()` breaks a path down into two parts (head and tail). I.e. C:/Folder/File.txt would be broken down into C:/Folder and File.txt. But I may be wrong as I may have misunderstood the docs. I'm no python programmer.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea: Hrm you're probably right. It's been a while since i did anything in python. I'll amend to my answer.

Comment: GetFileName still isn't similar to os.path.split() will also return the last folder in a path. I.e. C:\Foo\Bar would be C:\Foo, Bar.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea: There is no direct equivalent to `os.path.split()` then. You'll have to use `.GetFileName(string)` and `.GetDirectoryName(string)` to get the two parts.

Comment: `os.path.split()` gives you a head and a tail of the path. It does not JUST give you the filename. If there's no filename then it gives you the last folder in the path. I.e. like I said in my previous comment, it should return head: C:\Foo and tail: Bar from the example C:\Foo\Bar. So, GetFileName is not the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Path.GetFileName
Path.GetDirectoryName

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/beth2052.aspx
Should help

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use IronPython and get the best of both worlds?